# how to send image from one activity to another taken from gallery?

Tags: android

I am beginner to android, and i can't seem to find to find the solution for this question.

I wanted to send a image from one activity to another taken from gallery but whatever I do doesn't work help would be appreciated.
code to select image from gallery

Comment: You should not send the image file itself. Instead send the obtained uri.

Comment: Further selecting from gallery is something else. It is unclear where you encounter a problem.

Comment: Can you add some snippet of code that you have tried. and probably also the error log if there is any? I might help debugging the issue better and give you quicker and specific answers

Answer (score 0):

Main Activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
   public void SendImage(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("resId", R.drawable.image);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ImageView imageView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
      imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
      if (bundle != null) {
         int resId = bundle.getInt("resId");
         imageView.setImageResource(resId);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to pass the image between activities.If you have that image on your drawable folder you can directly use that on any activities.like below

```
ImageView iv =(ImageView) findVIewByID(R.id.image);
iv.setImage(getresources.getDrawable(R.drawable.filename);
```

or else you can use xml attribute on Imageview like

```
android:src="@drawable/filename"
```

add this line to your imageview.

If you have imageurl, you can pass as a string.You can pass a string in intent from first activity and you can get it from the next activity.Then using that url you can populate the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

For Capturing Image oR Select image from gallery First You need Permission . After Getting the permission you can choose image from gallery and then you can do whatever you want.
Here is a [Link](https://github.com/Toufiqulhaquemamun/Shetu_android/blob/c21aed33098db68fbccab1c345a1bfd193add3d8/app/src/main/java/com/example/amir/shetu/fragment/SaleMarketingFragment.java#L68) of Full Example.